# Recursive split function

Tags: python, string, recursion

I´m trying to write a function that takes a string and divides it into two strings. The first should only contains lowercase letters and the second only uppercase letter.

I have come up with a working solution but I want to be able to have a single function that goes through the string only once. I have tried an entire day now but haven't been able to come up with a solution so I would like some help.

The tricky part is that I must do this using recursion.
I have already come up with an iterative solution which was pretty easy but as stated before I must do this in a recursive way.

It is a homework assignment so I'm not looking for someone to do the job for me but some hints and explanations would be very welcome.

This is the code I've written combining two functions:

```
    def split_rec1(str):
        if str == "":
            return str
        elif str[0].islower():
            return str[0] + split_rec1(str[1:]) 
        else:
        return split_rec1(str[1:])

    def split_rec2(str):
        if str == "":
            return str
        elif str[0].isupper():
            return str[0] + split_rec2(str[1:])
        else:
            return split_rec2(str[1:])

    def split_rec(str):
        return (split_rec1(str), split_rec2(str))
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty nice homework question.

Answer (score 1):

reminder that you can iterate through a strings characters with a for loop so:

```
for c in s: print(c)
```

will print each character. Also, that you can concatenate strings such like:

```
'c' + 'b' == 'cb'
```

With this in mind:

```
>>> def split_case(s):
    uppers = ''
    lowers = ''
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper(): uppers += c
        else: lowers += c
    return(uppers,lowers)
```

Will do what you want:

```
>>> split_case("ThisIStheSTRiNg")
('TISSTRN', 'histheig')
```

This is however, not recursive. Since it is homework, I will leave the rest to you ;)

Comment: This is not recursive.

Comment: check the edit haha, i forgot to add in that comment

Answer (score 1):

You need your function to return two values (possibly in a tuple) as it descends through the recursion

As you don't want a complete answer, how about just the 'terminating' case:

```
def split_rec(str):
    if str == "":
        return ("","")
```

EDIT - as a complete answer has now been posted, here is my version of the complete answer without the ROT13 encoding this time.

```
def split_rec(str):
    if str == "":
        return ("","")
    up, low = split_rec(str[1:])
    if str[0].isupper():
        return (str[0]+up,low)
    if str[0].islower():
        return (up,str[0]+low)
    else:
        return (up,low)
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper function to have a tuple holding upper cased and lower cased strings (shortens main function):

```
def addtuple(t1, t2):
    return tuple(x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(t1, t2))
```

This is the main recursive function (returns a tuple of `(upper, lower)`):

```
def split_lower_upper(s):

    # base case - empty string has no upper/lower case letters
    if not s:
        return ("", "")

    # current character is the first character
    c = s[0]

    # if it is an uppercase we add it to upper-cased letters
    if c.isupper():
        return addtuple((c, ""), split_lower_upper(s[1:]))

    # if it is an uppercase we add it to lower-cased letters
    if c.islower():
        return addtuple(("", c), split_lower_upper(s[1:]))

    # if it's ont upper/lower case we filter it by ignoring it
    return split_lower_upper(s[1:])
```

**Tip**: Don't [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `str`. It can cause the most annoying bugs (and is just a bad practice).

Comment: you don't need the helper function to use a tuple (see the complete example in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to like recursive solutions that halve the problem at each stage rather than linearly whittling away at it.

```
def split_lower_upper(s):
    if len(s) > 1:
        mid = int(len(s) / 2)
        lower_1, upper_1 = split_lower_upper(s[:mid])
        lower_2, upper_2 = split_lower_upper(s[mid:])
        return (lower_1 + lower_2, upper_1 + upper_2)
    if s.isupper():
        return ("", s)
    else:
        return (s, "")

print(split_lower_upper("tNhIaCtEs"))   # => ('thats', 'NICE')
```